# Requested link only answers

Tags: discussion, review, link-only-answers

In going through the review tool I often come across poor quality answers to poor quality questions. In particular, I will occasionally see questions that are simply asking for links to products, asking for tools, etc. Here are three examples that I've come across just this morning.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18026
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16762
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16535

Clearly it's appropriate to go to the question and vote to close it (these are examples of not constructive) if they aren't already closed, but what should be done with the answers?

Should the answer be marked for deletion? Much of the normal reasoning for not providing link only answers is defeated if the question is simply asking for links. I'm tempted to mark them as 'looks good' for that reason, because it's the question that is flawed. Is that correct, or should I evaluate all answers as if they were responding to a quality question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I vote to close or delete the question, I leave the answer in the queue ("Not Sure") so others can see it as well. Hoping that the bad question will eventually be deleted and take the answer with it.

Voting separately for both the question and the answer seems like a waste of the precious votes. But I wouldn't say "Looks Good" if it doesn't.

Comment: There's no limit to the number of votes you have in the low quality queue, so that's not really an issue here.  Additionally, if everyone just hits 'not sure' it then it will be there forever.

Comment: There is for some. If you have 20k rep "Recommend Deletion" is shown as "Delete" and the vote is actually voting to delete. And that counts against your daily limit.

Comment: That makes sense.