# What's the proper action for LQP reviews of answers to shopping questions?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I came across [this low quality post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2690900).

The answer is of, at best, minimal value. It's a link only answer without a link; all you can do is search against the supplied product name.

I hesitate to select link only answer, though that would apply, because it's on a shopping question which just solicits links. All the other answers are only links as well, so it seems to me that deleting the reviewed answer for that reason might cause some cognitive dissonance in the poster, or fail to offer any insight as to why the question and answer aren't appropriate.

None of the other canned "recommend deletion" choices are valid. I could edit in a link to the product (and fix the other issues in the post), but I'm concerned that doing so would send the wrong message; that such answers are appropriate.

What's the correct review action to take here? I'm not wondering what to do about the question; I've already flagged it for closure.

Comment: The view of the deleted comments here does not reveal the hilarity that ensued in real-time. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Care to share?

Comment: A question born from a misread, a clarifying reply, and a separate one. Each posted immediately after the prior had been deleted.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was actually a duplicate, but the fact that the OP himself voted to close it as such put me over the edge. I really like clicking that "close" button. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go ahead and recommend deletion or vote to delete. Even if the question solicits links or recommendations, that doesn't suddenly make *just* a link an acceptable answer. Explaining why the link or recommendation is suitable or why you use it would be a much better answer.

Just because a question solicits opinions and should be closed doesn't mean we should leave it a link dump. Further (and I've said this before), just because a question is closed doesn't mean we shouldn't get rid of non-answers.

Answer (score 3):

As with any answer that is doing nothing but recommending a product, the first thing I always do is go look at the question.  In a significant percentage of cases, the question is doing nothing but asking for product recommendations.  That happens to be the case for this particular question as well.

In such circumstances it's important to close the question first (if that has not already been done).  That's more important than dealing with the answer.

Once you've dealt with the question by voting to close (or possibly delete and/or downvote), you can generally just ignore the answer, as per [this previous discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144656/requested-link-only-answers).  Hopefully the question will just be deleted, taking all of the spam answers along with it.